# Prevent dll from being modified

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm coding a C++ WinAPI DLL for a game, it includes a small anti-cheat function, but it can be easily bypassed if someone decides to NOP (0x90) the whole anti-cheat (I'm not PRO in reverse engineering but I'm sure it's possible to do).

Is there anyway to prevent my DLL from being modified?

Comment: simply said: no. Someone with enough time, or enough money to buy that time, can do whatever he/she desires. You'd better spend your own time on something more important.

Comment: You could calculate a hash value of the DLLs file and get the main program to check that. It doesn't prevent modification but could detect it. However, anything like this that you do will only slow down an attacker not stop them.

Comment: @jcoder: If I was a cracker, I would just patch the conditional jump which decides what happens if a DLL doesn't match some expected checksum.

Comment: Well you could do something trickier such as using the hash value to decrypt the configuration settings. You can always make it harder for an attacker, but like I said, you only make it harder, not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can stop people from modifying your DLL, there's nothing stopping someone from replacing your DLL with their own version that behaves just like yours in all aspects that your .exe can determine, but that does something different in some particular aspects - unless you keep an entire copy of the DLL in the .exe too.

It is better spending time and effort on making it hard to cheat than hard to change the .dll. Say for example that we have a Pac-Man game (because most people would be familiar with it), then we could send the number (and locations?) of all the "white pills" that Pac-Man ate on the path, and the time it took to get there. If the game then edits the .dll to give 10x the score for each white pill, or edits the game so that Pac-Man moves 10x faster, you can verify that it can't be right, because at each level you'd know how fast Pac-Man moved, and how many points per white pill Pac-Man should get. Number of times the player got killed and such could also be included in this information sent to the server.

A similar principle can be be applied to a "shoot-em-up" game, or a game that relies on buying and selling stuff, or whatever. If you have a detailed log of what the player did to get the score, you can validate that "this is possible" or "this is impossible to acheive, because you can't get that score from shooting down 10 space-ships in 1 second, as one space-ship takes 10 hits to shoot down, and it takes 1 second to fire each round".

Comment: This question is similar to a question I was about to ask. How would you handle information that is sensitive. Using your pac-man example, I would generally have some type of key that validates this is a real client talking to my server. If they spoof their traffic using the key from my dll and provide top scores that are reasonable how would I tell? Also how should I secure information like a client token?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you'll be better off moving any anti-cheat functionality to the server side, or if it's not a multiplayer game, then don't bother trying to stop cheats at all.

One thing you could do though is generate a hash of your DLL and check it in the application code against a known value or against a service or website. You could also use the hash value of the file for some other tasks as well essentially forcing the hacker to extensively modify the game code not just the anti-cheat function. That may deter people.

But the comments are right, with enough time and resources anything is hackable, you just need to make it not worth the time.

Comment: But how can I prevent anti-dll injection in server-side?